# DPDK occurs "failed to allocate private data" in rte_eal_init-a possibly unknown dpdk bug?

Tags: dpdk

When I searched for this problem, I found that almost **no one else encountered such a problem**.It's strange.By the way, I use dpdk-19.11.12 and Ubuntu-20.04

After looking at the dpdk source code, I know that the above code is in the **rte_eth_dev_create** function:

```
    if (priv_data_size) {
        ethdev->data->dev_private = **rte_zmalloc_socket**(
            name, priv_data_size, RTE_CACHE_LINE_SIZE,
            device->numa_node);

        if (!ethdev->data->dev_private) {
            RTE_LOG(ERR, EAL, "failed to allocate private data");
            retval = -ENOMEM;
            goto probe_failed;
        }
    }
```

It seems **rte_zmalloc_socket** return a NULL pointer. Why this happens?I allocated the relevant hugepage memory as requested.

Some Information：

```
EAL: Detected 4 NUMA nodes
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'PA'
EAL: No available hugepages reported in hugepages-2048kB
EAL: Probing VFIO support...
EAL: VFIO support initialized
EAL: PCI device 0000:31:00.0 on NUMA socket 3
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:1521 net_e1000_igb
EAL: PCI device 0000:31:00.1 on NUMA socket 3
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:1521 net_e1000_igb
EAL: PCI device 0000:51:00.0 on NUMA socket 5
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:10fb net_ixgbe
failed to allocate private data
EAL: Requested device 0000:51:00.0 cannot be used
EAL: PCI device 0000:51:00.1 on NUMA socket 5
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:10fb net_ixgbe
failed to allocate private data
EAL: Requested device 0000:51:00.1 cannot be used
```

**Hugepages：** (cat /proc/meminfo | grep Huge)

```
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
FileHugePages:         0 kB
HugePages_Total:      20
HugePages_Free:       19
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:    1048576 kB
Hugetlb:        20971520 kB
```

**and mount information:**
(mount | grep huge)

```
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,pagesize=1024M)
nodev on /mnt/huge type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,pagesize=1024M)
```

**NIC:**

```
Network devices using DPDK-compatible driver
============================================
0000:51:00.0 '82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection 10fb' drv=igb_uio unused=ixgbe,vfio-pci
0000:51:00.1 '82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection 10fb' drv=igb_uio unused=ixgbe,vfio-pci

Network devices using kernel driver
===================================
0000:31:00.0 'I350 Gigabit Network Connection 1521' if=enp49s0f0 drv=igb unused=igb_uio,vfio-pci 
0000:31:00.1 'I350 Gigabit Network Connection 1521' if=enp49s0f1 drv=igb unused=igb_uio,vfio-pci *Active*
```

**Numa information:**(numactl -H)

```
node 5 cpus: 30 31 32 33 34 35 78 79 80 81 82 83
node 5 size: 64475 MB
node 5 free: 58743 MB
```

82599ES NICs are on numa node 5.

I thought I did all the initialization but rte_eal_init returned the error "failed to allocate private data"

Any ideas on this issue? Thanks for help.

-----------------------update-----------------------------------------

Since this problem occurs in rte_zmalloc_socket(),I guess that there is something wrong with my configuration in Hugepages.But as posted above,i check Hugepages with command:

```
1.cat /proc/meminfo | grep Huge
2.mount | grep huge
```

first command checks available 1G Hugepages and second checks mount situation.

Result above seems to be normal which confuses me most.

Any clues?Thanks.

Comment: not sure who deleted my comments, so sharing again. The assumption of `type field is causing the problem is not correct`. This is because `both rte_zmalloc_socket and rte_malloc_socket internally calls heap_alloc` which basically ignores. Based on the log analysis `the NIC used is from `socket 5`, while the core which initializes the nic is `not from socket 5`. So to fix this issue, either `set NIC to NUMA same as lcore` or `use a lcore from the same numa as NIC and use --socket-mem=0,0,0,0,1024`. This should work around the problem.

Comment: please share `1) lscpu | grep NUMA, 2) EAL args used for running the test` for further analysis.

Comment: thanks for help:),I solve this prolem by answer below.

Comment: based on the answer you have posted, the NUMA alloc was indeed the problem. Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, the issue has been resolved.

The cause of the problem is that my cpu has 8 numa nodes and nics bound to dpdk are on node 5,**but by default dpdk only supports 4 numa nodes.**

My experience of finding the problem is like this：

1. **rte_eth_dev_create** calls **rte_zmalloc_socket** to allocate private-data
2. **rte_zmalloc_socket** directly calls **rte_malloc_socket**:

   ```
   void *
   rte_zmalloc_socket(const char *type, size_t size, unsigned align, int socket)
   {
     void *ptr = rte_malloc_socket(type, size, align, socket);

   #ifdef RTE_MALLOC_DEBUG
    /*
    * If DEBUG is enabled, then freed memory is marked with poison
    * value and set to zero on allocation.
    * If DEBUG is not enabled then  memory is already zeroed.
    */
      if (ptr != NULL)
         memset(ptr, 0, size);
     #endif
         return ptr;
   }
   ```
3. **rte_malloc_socket** calls **malloc_heap_alloc** with socket_arg = 5 in my case:

   ```
   void *
   rte_malloc_socket(const char *type, size_t size, unsigned int align, int socket_arg)
   {
   /* return NULL if size is 0 or alignment is not power-of-2 */
   if (size == 0 || (align && !rte_is_power_of_2(align)))
       return NULL;

   /* if there are no hugepages and if we are not allocating from an
    * external heap, use memory from any socket available. checking for
    * socket being external may return -1 in case of invalid socket, but
    * that's OK - if there are no hugepages, it doesn't matter.
    */
   if (rte_malloc_heap_socket_is_external(socket_arg) != 1 &&
              !rte_eal_has_hugepages())
        socket_arg = SOCKET_ID_ANY;

     return malloc_heap_alloc(type, size, socket_arg, 0,
           align == 0 ? 1 : align, 0, false);
   }
   ```

4.In **malloc_heap_alloc**:

```
void*
malloc_heap_alloc(const char *type, size_t size, int socket_arg, unsigned int 
 flags, size_t align, size_t bound, bool contig)

{
    int socket, heap_id, i;
    void *ret;

   /* return NULL if size is 0 or alignment is not power-of-2 */
   if (size == 0 || (align && !rte_is_power_of_2(align)))
      return NULL;

   if (!rte_eal_has_hugepages() && socket_arg < RTE_MAX_NUMA_NODES)
       socket_arg = SOCKET_ID_ANY;

   if (socket_arg == SOCKET_ID_ANY)
       socket = malloc_get_numa_socket();
   else
       socket = socket_arg;

   /* turn socket ID into heap ID */
   **heap_id = malloc_socket_to_heap_id(socket);**
   /* if heap id is negative, socket ID was invalid */
   **if (heap_id < 0)
       return NULL;**
   ...
}
```

My program returns NULL because **heap_ip = -1 while socket = 5**,which eventually causes rte_zamlloc_socket return NULL and failed to allocate private data for nics.

By running " **meson configure** " in dpdk build directory,I got such result:

```
max_numa_nodes     4      maximum number of NUMA nodes supported by EAL
```

So in my case, I need to use either one of the steps to rebuild dpdk.

1. rebuild from scratch "**cd [dpdk parent folder]; rm -rf build; meson -Dmax_numa_nodes=8 build**"
2. to reuse existing build folder "**cd [dpdk parent folder]; meson --reconfigure -Dmax_numa_nodes=8 build**"

After that, everything is back to normal.

Thanks for help,and hope this can help anyone else why meet the same problem.:)